# Can I deserialize a JSON object by object in C#?

Tags: c#, json, object, deserialization

I have a big json file. It consist of information of different articles posted on internet. I'm wandering if it's possible to deserialize it object by object. For example, to make a loop and with every iteration a single object from json to be deserialized, then the next one, and so on.

Here are just only two of json file's objects (there are some thousands out there)

```
[
  {
    "source": "unimedia",
    "title": "some title",
    "original_time": "ora: 20:03, 06 dec 2006",
    "datetime": "2006-12-06T20:03:00+00:00",
    "views": 398,
    "comments": 1,
    "content": " some content",
    "id": "13",
    "url": "http://unimedia.info/stiri/-13.html"
  },

   {
    "source": "unimedia",
    "title": "some another title",
    "original_time": "ora: 20:13, 06 dec 2006",
    "datetime": "2006-12-06T20:13:00+00:00",
    "views": 173,
    "comments": 1,
    "content": "some another content",
    "id": "19",
    "url": "http://unimedia.info/stiri/-19.html"
  },
    ...
]
```

Here is my class:

```
class jsonData
    {
        public string source { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string original_time { get; set; }
        public string datetime { get; set; }
        public int views { get; set; }
        public int comments { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anybody help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use use Newtonsoft.Json

[Newtonsoft Json](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

```
 string json = File.ReadAllText(PathFile);
 jsonData obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonData>(json);
```

Comment: Okay, but your suggested usage (code example) completely misses the point of the OP's question: he wants to deserialize one object at a time, from an enumerator, presumably from a stream, because the file is huge.

Comment: i just give him an example of how he could proceed and let the rest for him , if he need more help i m here with u